# Product of Polynomials is polynomial over an integral closure then so are those individual polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am stuck with this problem from atiyah's commutative algebra.

It asks that

> If $A\subset B$ be integral domains and $C$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $B$, then for monic polynomials $f,g\in B[x]$ if $fg \in C[x]$, then $f,g \in C[x]$.

I referred to the hint and here is my proof,in detail so please check if it is correct.

consider the field of fractions of K of the integral domain B, then $fg\in K[x]$ and hence there is a splitting field of $fg$, and suppose that $\{a_i\}_i, \{b_j\}_j$ are roots of $f$ and $g$ in K, then $\{a_i\}_i, \{b_j\}_j$ are integral over $C$ because $fg$ is a monic polynomial in $C$. Further since $C$ is integral over $A$, that would imply that the elements of $K$ that is $\{a_i\}_i, \{b_j\}_j$ are integral over $A$. Now the coefficients of $f$ are expressions in $\{a_i\}_i$ and hence the coefficients of $f$ are integral over $A$. But since $f$ lies in $B$, so the coefficients lie in $C$.
Other solutions I had refered wouldn't show that they are integral over $A$, so I was trying to understand that. So we have the conclusion.

Looks correct?

Further If $A \subset B$ are not integral domains, then they want to show that the polynomial has roots in a larger field and they will repeat the argument above. For that they are using induction on degree of $f$ and saying that this is a field $$\frac{B[x]}{<f(x)>}$$ but here is the confusion.

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_6[x]}{<x^2+1>}$$ is not a field even though the polynomial is irreducible because $2.3=0$ so I would like a bit of explaination here.

Apologies for poor formatting. I cannot type so long without my near & dear laptop which is not working.

Comment: $f$, $g$ have to be monic. Otherwise you can have $f$, $g$ constants in $C$, with product in $C$, but neither in $C$, like the example of $A= C= \mathbb{Z}$, $B= \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: assumed that. I have written it explicitly now. Thanks